# Edited title after partial solution: This div hovers over the rest of the contents, and adding `height:100%` to body solves this. Why?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

**I just solved the problem** by adding `height:100%;` to `html` and `body`, **but couldn't figure out the exact reason**. So now I am changing the question from "Why does this div appear hovering over its sibling div, rather than appearing after it?" to what you see in the title.

You can see my answer for the JSFiddle showing this solution, and now the question is why does that solve the problem.

---

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/o4zmya9o/2/)**

In the following SSCCE, I want the `.content-other-than-slider` to be below the first/top viewport (which in this page's layout is represented by `first-viewport`), so that it is Not visible until the user scrolls down.

I have been fiddling with `positon`s but could not do that. So the question is that **how can I do that?**

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert("Meh! Meh!");//check

  var numberOfImages = $('#imageSlideshowContainer > img').length;
  var currentImage = 1;

  /**
   * Previous Arrow Code
   **/
  $('.previous-slide-arrow').click(function() {
    $('img.slider-image' + currentImage).hide();
    $('span.caption' + currentImage).hide();
    $('a.navigation-bullet' + currentImage).removeClass('active');

    currentImage--;

    if (currentImage == 0) {
      currentImage = numberOfImages;
    }

    $('img.slider-image' + currentImage).show();
    $('span.caption' + currentImage).show();
    $('a.navigation-bullet' + currentImage).addClass('active');

    return false;
  });


  /**
   * Next Arrow Code
   **/
  $('.next-slide-arrow').click(function() {
    $('img.slider-image' + currentImage).hide();
    $('span.caption' + currentImage).hide();
    $('a.navigation-bullet' + currentImage).removeClass('active');

    currentImage++;

    if (currentImage == numberOfImages + 1) {
      currentImage = 1;
    }

    $('img.slider-image' + currentImage).show();
    $('span.caption' + currentImage).show();
    $('a.navigation-bullet' + currentImage).addClass('active');

    return false;
  });

  /**
   * Bullets Code
   **/
  function changeImage(imageNumber) {
    $('img.slider-image' + currentImage).hide();
    $('span.caption' + currentImage).hide();
    currentImage = imageNumber;
    $('img.slider-image' + currentImage).show();
    $('span.caption' + currentImage).show();

    $('.navigation-bullets-wrapper a').removeClass('active');

    $('a.navigation-bullet' + imageNumber).addClass('active');
  }


  /**
   * Automatic Timer to change Slides
   * Copy paste the same code from next arrow, and insert a special function setInterval which will run another function every x seconds you set.
   **/
  function autoChangeSlides() {
    $('img.slider-image' + currentImage).hide();
    $('span.caption' + currentImage).hide();
    $('a.navigation-bullet' + currentImage).removeClass('active');

    currentImage++;

    if (currentImage == numberOfImages + 1) {
      currentImage = 1;
    }

    $('img.slider-image' + currentImage).show();
    $('span.caption' + currentImage).show();
    $('a.navigation-bullet' + currentImage).addClass('active');
  }

  var slideTimer = setInterval(function() {
    autoChangeSlides()
  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
.first-page {
  height: 100%;
}
.image-slideshow-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
.image-slideshow-container img {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
img.slider-image1 {
  display: block;
}
.first-viewport {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
}
a.previous-slide-arrow,
a.next-slide-arrow {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  left: 20px;
  width: 3%;
}
a.next-slide-arrow {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
.previous-slide-arrow:hover,
.next-slide-arrow:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  color: transparent;
}
.central-content-container {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  padding: 20px 5px;
}
.central-content-container span {
  display: none;
}
.central-content-container a {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background: #b9b8b8;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.central-content-container a:hover {
  background: #e8e3e3;
}
.central-content-container a.active {
  background: white;
}
/*....................................................*/

a.learn-more-link {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.95);
  text-size: 30px;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}
.learn-more-link-wrapper {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.learn-more-link-wrapper .learn-more-image {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 40px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.learn-more-link-wrapper .learn-more-image:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider-text-wrapper {} .slider-text-wrapper span {
  display: none;
}
.slider-text-wrapper span h3,
.slider-text-wrapper span p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px
}
.slider-text-wrapper span h3 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 68px;
}
.slider-text-wrapper span h3 strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.slider-text-wrapper span p {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.slider-text-wrapper .caption1 {
  display: block;
}
.first-viewport {
  top: 0px;
}
.caption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
.content-other-than-slider p {
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: wheat;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-page">

  <div id="imageSlideshowContainer" class="image-slideshow-container">

    <img class="slider-image1" src="http://shutupandtakemethere.com/pics/022014/stairs-in-a-japanese-garden-big.jpg" alt="pitcher!" />

    <img class="slider-image2" src="http://piximus.net/media/9366/beautiful-places-on-the-world-20.jpg" alt="pitcher!" />

    <img class="slider-image3" src="http://freetopwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/free-beautiful-place-wallpaper-hd-161.jpg" alt="pitcher!" />

    <img class="slider-image4" src="http://www.countrysideshow.co.uk/sites/default/files/imagecache/HP_SS1_990x514/rotor/hh%20ss%201.jpg"
    alt="pitcher!" />

  </div>




  <div class="first-viewport">

    <a class="previous-slide-arrow" href="#">&lt;</a>


    <div class="central-content-container">
      <div class="slider-text-wrapper">
        <span class="caption caption1">DESCRIPTION TEXT</span>
        <span class="caption caption2">DESCRIPTION TEXT</span>
        <span class="caption caption3">DESCRIPTION TEXT</span>
        <span class="caption caption4">DESCRIPTION TEXT</span>
      </div>

      <div class="learn-more-link-wrapper">
        <img class="read-more-image" src="http://www.abacusinstitute.ac.nz/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/readmore.png" />
      </div>

      <div class="navigation-bullets-wrapper">
        <a class="active navigation-bullet1" href="javascript: changeImage(1)">
          <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
        <a class="navigation-bullet2" href="javascript: changeImage(2)">
          <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
        <a class="navigation-bullet3" href="javascript: changeImage(3)">
          <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
        <a class="navigation-bullet4" href="javascript: changeImage(4)">
          <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- navigation bullets wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- central-content-container -->

    <a class="next-slide-arrow" href="#">&gt;</a>
  </div>
  <!-- first-viewport -->

</div>
<!-- first-page -->

<div class="content-other-than-slider">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<!-- content-other-than-slider -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `height:100%;` to `body` solved the problem.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o4zmya9o/3/).

But I am yet not clear about why does that solve the problem, so if somebody knows that, I will like them to still post an answer or edit this one.

*Note: I would delete the question since it is solved, and does not have any answers yet, but I think the question might be useful for future visitors.*